# Prove that characteristic of $R$ is $2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R$ be a unit ring (not a field) such that for all $x\in R$ that is not invertible, $x^2=x$. Show that $R$ has characteristic $2$.

**Try:** Let $x\in R$ be non invertible, we have that $x^2=x$. Then, $$(x+x)^2=x+x$$ $$x^2+2x+x^2=x+x$$ $$x+2x+x=x+x$$ $$ 2x=0.$$ This shows that for $x$ that are not invertible, $2x=0$. But that does not show that it has characteristic $2$, because it remains to be seen that the same thing happens for the invertible $x$. Any help for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, as $R$ is not a field we can choose $x\in R$ a non-unit non-zero element. Then your argument shows $2x=0$. From this it follows that $2$ is not a unit, for if it were, then
$$2^{-1}2x=x\not=0$$
but $2x=0$ which is a contradiction. So as $2$ is a non-unit $4=2^2=2$ hence $2=0$ and the ring has characteristic $2$.

Comment: Non-unit means non-invertible.

Comment: Should you show that, if $x$ is non-invertible, the so is $x+x$?

Comment: @Empy2 That's always true. If $x$ is a non-unit, then $1\not\in\left<x\right>$ so $\left<x\right>$ cannot contain any units, hence $2x\in\left<x\right>$ is a non-unit.

Comment: @JamesA. We showed $2=0$, which is all need for the ring to have characteristic $2$. In general the characteristic of the ring is the additive order of $1$. This is because $\sum_{i=1}^nx=nx$ so if $n=0$ we have $nx=0x=0$.

Comment: @Melody I have a question, to use the hypothesis that x^2=x with the number 2 you would have to have two things, that $2\in R$ and that $2^2=4$ in $R$ as well, but how do you know that? I don't understand that part to conclude.

Comment: @JamesA. You said a unital ring, so $2=1+1\in R$. And $$2^2=2*2=2(1+1)=2+2=4$$ In general the subgroup generated by $1$ is always isomorphic as a group to a quotient of $\mathbb{Z}$ and because of the distributive property that isomorphism is actually an isomorphism of rings.